# Typescript Generic with satisfies

Tags: typescript

I'm sticking with Typings,
Before I had a map with `Record<Tag, TagDataConfig>` and I used to query using `TagConfigurations[Tag.PH_STANDARD]`. It worked pretty well, but now sometime I need to inject some values to generate the configuration.

I'm trying to create a function that gives the same behavior with type inference but resolves the injection function if required.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgcygbwFBSgBQBIH0DKMAggHIAiRASmVALxQAMANOlnppQKICyAkgKrc6UAIwsMOApxiYA8rxIxhAJlQBfVKlCQoZOABc4MAJ4AHYClYlBAIU6UmZSrMxlZAdRKOAmiSJ8AYVxrbjsHGF5uTlxKUgBxTnVNAEsQfWAAJwAzOABjC3wACzgM4AATTAyAe1MAZ0sMfSqAMWSAD3KALihwCAAjTIBuVlrgfUwq1P0Afm74BGGNLTbTKoz9KCnMnPyoAKqICCqQeb1DfZAs5KRgNvSQMvqikvLKmvq0RrNgbrOjb4AdE4XG5PFAAD66Az-cwAkJhCFQwwmWFkXz+XhBeH2YYYWrpUzdXoDDK4qAQVJEyAkskQOBtKn9IasKpZLKjGZzRCLTS3VbrTZpbZ5CwwZIQYCUOAgBDAP4XK43O6gR5QZ6lCrVOoNKD6b6-aEo4AAiJRGLxThkvpgZIAGzKfwAFABKbr8KYADiIGQycGMPNQevMsEQ8uOiuE+0Ox1O0IV10RYolUplcrj4eumiDotD6cu10wJVGzTAIFy+mSx2Ejv0toAboySUxyVUysBbY3Ms2siBupRgLk1mUADz4jKpBDNvpVKq24DSgB8zroC5DCDD+YQvJWaw2g5A+LX8YQYF9FeO9XonygAG15gDJIRSBRqABdbrXjB0hlQADsAIANnEDByUpKAAIBD1gLxMYJimLkEAfPB8GkOQFBgaCoHxYBCUYAExFYRoWnaLpREw7MDWRQFsQcVg1GAu9ECQ3AOB4ARuHfKBHVwZtcB4lAoFMLVd0rEA4FtKA1GXWhV0dT9yXpbp-yAwjQN7cDIMwjk4LSBDmJQmR5EULSCW6Bh8PI4iOjKbohJqETjnEqBpigZQoG6AiQN1fUkRhY0aOAqT1CwgxklqK5gHqQt1mScTh37QcMhHeZm1jc4MyQSE0rgY9ouLUty1EhcF2GQNvjXdxkn0Qpj2EABrYBjFZbzzGa+Zj1PUKL1K7MoFaMTbXajLh1q257lVbLaqy3N0s3PLgBLMtzxAVdaFQUblQeepHVYWsGx6aku1YI42w7A6mQyYCez7Ach1HfRxxlKcZznRcWGk1dUiyTIoH7fRTxAcpj1YFy-oBoGMtYbpj1K5Z+Q2LICuWqBSlqWc62AIbNxG09SjSeYoDGlV6nmSrquPBcdsaRBodx0B9BS3b607S7jtbdsWaupHRNqG7EpHMcJ2e2d5xW97un68SscVYdszaxAOrPHmbwCOn8cQV9V2vfdD0MBBavoaXrk65bahvPXX1hjBkiyLi5dtvWDdoegACJEaW0SXeXeSAHofagMnCiqMA9zgfEJygF2w5d5sHuuWUMkJn01lU0p-oyEBdQVjKa3rZsTvbbtuYvZ1NC8v2A6qwpmyqqAAHc1jq2pVIrtOAaz-Wc72-P2dtIuPZLqAw761Ipez7H7Y7im6LLqAK8D4PQ-DmVI+j2PxwQBOk+qDJWDbjOp8hjB56rmuNgbjIm9YVuxnbx2MqH+pJcG8eZcn+-NxKpJUHdwqqzpVIud9rEi7C2U6nMoC-1NnzO6gsnpQGnCLRczprwV3wMAYAEB6hNHro3eu7YJKFEyMAVgOsNilDgGUAmhsmKPmIOQKgZAyRkJRvOKhr8Ez0FRujTGHCECOgoewycuo85gMLpA4uB5nTMIvBsKo1VMjULXMxVifBBAyIPHIhRGQjZIC4ZFHhujHTyKIToxAsdREFz7hIgeUiyRqCAA)

```
enum Tag {
  PH_STANDARD = 0,
  PH_PREMIUM = 1,
  PH_SETPOINT = 2
}

enum DataType {
  NUMBER,DROPDOWN,DYNAMIC_NUMBER,TIME_RANGE
}

interface SharedProps {
  toFixed: number;
  setPoint?: Tag;
}

export interface CommonTagDataConfig extends SharedProps {
  type: DataType.DROPDOWN | DataType.NUMBER | DataType.DYNAMIC_NUMBER;
  step: number;
  min: number;
  max: number;
  offset?: Tag;
}

export interface TimeRangeDataConfig extends SharedProps {
  type: DataType.TIME_RANGE;
  buildData(): Uint8Array;
}

type TagDataConfig = CommonTagDataConfig | TimeRangeDataConfig

type TagDataConfigParseFunction = (tlv: number, model: number, fn: Record<string, boolean>) => TagDataConfig

export const TagConfigurations = {
  [Tag.PH_STANDARD]: {
    max: 7.6,
    min: 6.8,
    setPoint: Tag.PH_SETPOINT,
    step: 0.1,
    toFixed: 1,
    type: DataType.NUMBER,
  },
  [Tag.PH_PREMIUM]: (_, __, { proportional }) => ({
    max: 7.6,
    min: 6.8,
    setPoint: Tag.PH_SETPOINT,
    step: 0.1,
    toFixed: proportional ? 2 : 1,
    type: DataType.NUMBER,
  })
} satisfies Partial<Record<Tag, TagDataConfig | TagDataConfigParseFunction>>;

type TagWithConfig = keyof typeof TagConfigurations;

type FinalTagConfig<Config extends TagDataConfig | TagDataConfigParseFunction> =
Config extends (
  tlv: number,
  model: number,
  fn: Record<string, boolean>,
) => infer ReturnedConfig
  ? ReturnedConfig
  : Config;


export function resolveTagConfig<CurrentTag extends TagWithConfig>(
  tag: CurrentTag,
  tlv: number,
  model: number,
  functions: Record<string, boolean>,
): FinalTagConfig<typeof TagConfigurations[CurrentTag]> {
  const tagConfig = TagConfigurations[tag];


  if (typeof tagConfig === "function") {
    // Without casting "as", trigger error
    return tagConfig(tlv, model, functions)

    // With, it works
    // return tagConfig(tlv, model, functions) as FinalTagConfig<typeof tagConfig>
  }

  // Without casting "as", trigger error
  return tagConfig
  // With, it works
  // return tagConfig as FinalTagConfig<typeof tagConfig>;
}

function main(tlv: number, model: number, functions: Record<string, boolean>){
  // Seems to work well here
  const readTag = Tag.PH_STANDARD;
  const readTagConfig = resolveTagConfig(readTag, tlv, model, functions);
  const otherTag = Tag.PH_PREMIUM;
  const otherTagConfig = resolveTagConfig(otherTag, tlv, model, functions);
  }
```

What's wrong ? Maybe simpler version ?

Thanks

Comment: *You* tell us what's wrong with your code. I have no idea what error you are getting! Also, this code is not enough to reproduce the problem; we are missing definitions for some types.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] which clearly demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.

Comment: Added a link and update example